# How to make a Textbox in a UserControl not receive focus on Load?

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, focus, tabindex

I have a XAML page where, upon tapping an "Add" button, I create a UserControl and add it to my Container. This UserControl has a Rectangle, a TextBox and a few buttons. My problem is that on the first click of the "Add" button, the focus is given to the Textbox. Clicking on the "Add" button repeatedly creates more UserControl instances, but focus remains on TextBox1. If I now click on Textbox5, that box gets focus, but as soon as I click outside, focus returns to Textbox1. I would like focus to be given to textboxes, only on click.

I have tried setting IsTabStop = true in XAML, and intercepting the tapped event and setting it to false, but that doesn't have a noticeable effect.

What worked perfectly is setting the TextBox's TabIndex = 2, and creating another button *before* it, and setting it's TabIndex = 1. But I lose this benefit when I set the Button's Visibility = Collapsed. The TextBox is the left most control, so it must have the lowest TabIndex (well technically, there is a Rectangle to the left of the TextBox, but since a Rectangle is not a Control, it cannot have a TabIndex).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is when you are adding more controls, it is resetting the current tab stop index. So every time you add a control, the TextBox of TabStop 1 is being focused on.

What you can do, is after you add the control, call `Focus()` on the control that you want to be focused.

Comment: Can I give focus to the Parent of the UserControl? To the container Grid in the parent, for instance?

Comment: I could be wrong but I do not think a Grid can have focus. You will need to set focus to another control, probably the button that was just pressed makes the most sense.

Comment: Also, there is no way to "remove focus" from all controls. You have to do as you said at that point and create a hidden button, and set focus onto that.